How to access then((title)) value outside of the function in javascript
I am writing cypress javascript code and try to access title attribute value from  and storing value into title.
When I print cy.log("Title Attribute: ", title); It works. but i want to access another function called getdocumentTitle(). but its not printing value.
Can somebody see what I am doing wrong.
 getdocumentTitle() {
    cy.log("Title : ", this.titlev);
    return this.titlev;
  }

readDocTitleAttributeByDocumentNameFromTableColumns(value) {
  let x;

  // Find the rows containing the desired text
  this.rowResponseSummaryTable.each(($row) => {
    // Check if the row contains the desired text
    cy.wrap($row)
      .find("td:nth-child(5)")
      .invoke("text")
      .then((text) => {
        if (text.trim() === value) {
          cy.wrap($row)
            .find("td:nth-child(2) > a")
            .invoke("attr", "title")
            .then((title) => {
              cy.log("Title Attribute: ", title);
              x = title; // Assign title to x
              this.titlev = x; // Assign x to this.titlev inside the inner then block
            });
        }
      });
  });

  // This log will execute before the inner Cypress commands are finished
  cy.log("Title X: ", x);

  // This assignment will execute before the inner Cypress commands are finished
  this.titlev = x;
}


readDocTitleAttributeByDocumentNameFromTableColumns(value) {
  return this.rowResponseSummaryTable.each(($row) => {
    return $row
      .find("td:nth-child(5)")
      .invoke("text")
      .then((text) => {
        if (text.trim() === value) {
          return $row
            .find("td:nth-child(2) > a")
            .invoke("attr", "title")
            .then((title) => {
              cy.log("Title Attribute: ", title);
              // You can use the title here or return it for further processing
              return title;
            });
        }
      });
  });
}

